# Time Format across multiple columns in a R dataframe?

Tags: r

How do I apply same format across other columns in the DataFrame
[image]

I am currently using the below code to change it, 
also, Can I also use For loops to do the same task, if so how?

```
  APR1 <-strptime(APR$Total.Ready.Duration, format ="%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
commonFormat <- as.data.frame(lapply(APR, strptime, format="%H:%M"))
```

will apply `strptime` to all columns of APR, and return the result as a list of columns and then join those columns up into a data.frame.  If you only want to change a subset of columns reformatted, change `APR` to `APR[[vectofOfColumns]]`.  You can re-insert into the original data.frame with `APR[[vectorOfColumns]] <- commonFormat`

Comment: The Code works but as I add a vector of columns ; "commonFormat <- as.data.frame(lapply(APR[,6:10], strptime, format="%H:%M"))" The code results only subset of data from 6 to 10 col. I just want 6 to 10 to be affected not a different dataframe.

Comment: A subset of columns?  If so, that is to be expected, and you can re-insert them into your original data.frame (or a copy of it), by APR[[6:10]] <- commonFormat, as implied in my answer.  But if you mean a subset of _rows_, then I can only imagine that is due to some of the values not being acceptable input into strptime.

Comment: Thanks I overlooked that instruction, I followed it and it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in start:end) APR[,i]<-strptime(APR[,i], format ="%H:%M")
```

where start denotes first column and end last column to change

or

```
cNames<-c('Total.Ready.Duration','Total.Break.Duration')

for (i %in% cNames) APR[,i]<-strptime(APR[,i], format ="%H:%M")
```

if you want to use colnames

Comment: for (i in 6:10) 
{  APR[,i] <- strptime(APR[,i], format ="%H:%M")
}

Comment: I tried the above but it didnt work gave me 6 lines of error like below     ;   In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(sec = c(NA_real_,  :
  provided 9 variables to replace 1 variables

Comment: What class are your columns?

Comment: Do you mean is it Factor or numerical? its Factor